# Redirection inside system command is not working?

Tags: php

I have a php code in which I am trying to redirect the output of a command to a file 
 My code is

```
<?php
 shell_exec("ls >txt.txt");
?>
```

But when I checked the file, nothing was inside!.This was working when I tried this command line, 
 what might be the issue?

Comment: Checked permission? Just because it works at the command line means nothing - that'd be running under YOUR permissions, not those of the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection is a shell (e.g. bash) feature so it won't work here. You need to do something like:

```
shell_exec("bash -c 'ls > txt.txt'");
```